# Which one is the delete button on an Apple keyboard?

Tags: keyboard, keybindings

I use the <kbd>cmd</kbd><kbd>backspace</kbd> shortcut but in some applications <kbd>fn</kbd><kbd>backspace</kbd> seems to work as well. So which one it the delete hotkey in OS X El Capitan?

Comment: You need to clarify **where** in El Capitan, fn/backspace & cmd/backspace perform totally different functions.

Comment: Do you want to know the key combo for file deletion or the "forward delete key" on the keyboard?

Answer (score 4):

A detailed description on this is available on this post https://superuser.com/questions/482771/difference-between-cmdbackspace-and-fnbackspace-keyboard-shortcuts-in-osx

#### To summarize:

- The most commonly used key for deleting elements that can be selected in the user interface is ***Backward Delete* <kbd>⌫</kbd>** since it's available without a modifier on all Apple keyboards. This applies to songs on a playlist, graphics in an image editor, deleting text boxes in Pages, etc.
- The ***Forward Delete* <kbd>fn</kbd><kbd>⌫</kbd>** is mostly used for the same actions, so you can actually use both in an interchangable way for most applications, be it Numbers, Excel, iTunes, Photoshop, etc.
- The ***combination*** <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>⌫</kbd> is intended for actions that might have an immediate (unwanted) effect. One could indeed map trashing files and folders to a simple <kbd>⌫</kbd>, but this could lead to accidental deletions. Finder uses the modifier as a safeguard. This also explains why iTunes will only delete a song *without* confirmation if you press the <kbd>⌘</kbd> modifier.

Comment: This answer is as confused as the question.

Comment: Much better - removed downvote :)

Answer (score 4):

In a text editor…

<kbd>Fn</kbd>   <kbd>Backspace ←</kbd>  is the equivalent of  <kbd>Delete ⌦</kbd> for short keyboards without that key

- <kbd>Backspace ←</kbd>  deletes the character before the cursor.
- <kbd>Delete ⌦</kbd> deletes the character after the cursor.
- <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>Backspace ←</kbd>  deletes the entire line before the cursor.
- <kbd>Opt ⌥</kbd>   <kbd>Backspace ←</kbd>  deletes the word before the cursor.
- <kbd>Opt ⌥</kbd>   <kbd>Delete ⌦</kbd> deletes the word after the cursor.

In the Finder…

- <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>Backspace ←</kbd>  deletes the selected file(s).
- <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>Delete ⌦</kbd> has no function.